# .htaccess redirect only redirects after the first link is clicked

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an .htaccess file that is supposed to be redirecting to several different domains/subdirectories:

```
RewriteEngine on

#this works
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainA\.ca$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/foundation%{REQUEST_URI}/ -d
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

#this works
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainB\.ca$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foundation/$1 [QSA,L]


#this sort of works
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domainC.ca/index.php?/$1 [R=301,QSA]
```

They have several more domains set up as aliases on the account domainD, domainE and so on. If someone requests domainD then the browser's address bar will say on domainD = no rewrite, as soon as they click a link they will get forwarded to domainC/whatever-link/ which is correct, but what am I missing to get the inital domainD -> domainC rewrite to work?

Comment: It is unclear what the problem is? Can you clarify?

Comment: when a user types domainD into the address bar, they stay on domainD, they need to be redirected to domainC

Answer (score 0):

You can try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domainC\.ca$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domainC.ca%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: I'm not so sure, the first line needs to be some kind of wildcard as there are several more domains that need to match that rule - and if it was a wild card, domainA & domainB won't get processed? The wild card needs to be last I think?

Comment: ok try edited code now. It basically says if domain != domainC then redirect.

Comment: Thanks, that does forward them on the first request, but now the FURLs don't work [i.e. all other requests get a 404]

Comment: Can you give me an example of URL that is causing 404

Comment: they are all like: domainC.com/directory/directory/file/

Comment: And what is correct path for `domainC.com/directory/directory/file/`

Comment: oh, it would look something like domainC.com?index.php&id=34&something=whatever etc...  it's a codeIgniter site.

Comment: Wow have you forgot to mention about CI so far :) Where is default CI rule?

Comment: originally only the last few lines were modified: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} . was added [I think] the last line was added and the line that is now commented out was not commented. the rest has not been touched.

Comment: I just removed all old rules and kept my suggested rule. Just make sure this is your very first rule in main CI .htaccess file